# modify .rb script test case to hit DownKey

Tags: ruby, selenium, webdriver

I have a ruby test case generated by selenium and I'm running the test case with WebDriver. At some point I have to pic a user from a dynamically generated list, and my user is always the first item in my list. How can I hit the DownKey to select a user from my list ? and Is it possible or not ? I've been searching the web for about two days and no luck

here is the code

.
.
.

@driver.find_element(:id, "email").send_keys "xxxxxx@xxxxx.com"

@driver.find_element(:id, "pass").clear

@driver.find_element(:id, "pass").send_keys "123456\n"

@driver.find_element(:id, "fb_friend").clear

@driver.find_element(:id, "fb_friend").send_keys "Ryan Wolf"

. >>>> this is the place that my list is generated and I have to pic the first name from my list by going down and hit enter  <<<<<<

.
.
.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do arrow down this way

```
@driver.find_element(:id, "fb_friend").send_keys [:arrow_down]
```

more options are [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Keys.html#KEYS-constant)